# R - DF frequency

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataset of all the matches played by LA Lakers from 2005 to 2015. It looks like this:

```
Hometeam         Guest           Result     Value
LA Lakers       NY Knicks          H         1
Chicago Bulls   LA Lakers          G         1
LA Lakers      Houston Rockets     D         0
LA Lakers       NY Knicks          H         1
Chicago Bulls   LA Lakers          G         1
LA Lakers      Houston Rockets     D         0
LA Lakers      Walsh HS            H         1
LA Lakers      Ga Tech             G         0
Akron Beacon    LA Lakers          G         1
New Orleans     LA Lakers          H         0
```

Where

```
     H - Home team won
     G - Guest team won
     D - Draw
```

Now, I want to find the frequencies in order to find the probability- of LA Lakers winning if they won a previous match.

How can I find the frequency of LA Lakers winning in two consecutive matches both playing in home and playing as guest. I'm trying to solve this in R. Thanks in Advance.

Now, I want to calculate the frequency of LA Lakers (won/lost) this game won/lost previous game.

So the four ordered pairs are (won P, won C),(won P, Lost C),(Lost P, Won C), (Lost P, Lost C).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, you can do :

```
library(dplyr)

#Win and win
df %>%  summarise(total = sum(Value == 1 & lag(Value, default = 0) == 1))

#Win and lose
df %>% summarise(total = sum(Value == 0 & lag(Value, default = 0) == 1))

#Lose and Win
df %>% summarise(total = sum(Value == 1 & lag(Value, default = 1) == 0))

#Lose and Lose
df %>% summarise(total = sum(Value == 0 & lag(Value, default = 1) == 0))
```

Comment: Hi @RonakShah, the question I'm trying to solve says that I have to create a new column which has values like 1 for win and 0 for L/D. I'm unable to figure it out from there....

Comment: @t.wangd To create a new column you can do `df %>%
  mutate(win = +(Hometeam == 'LA_Lakers' & Result == 'H' | 
                  Guest == 'LA_Lakers' & Result == 'G'))`

Comment: yes I did created a new column. But from there, I'm unable to figure out how to calculate the frequencies of the pairs possible.

Comment: I think that's what my answer does. Did you try to run it?

Comment: Hi @RonakShah, my df looks like this after adding the new column.                                  ```                                                                                                                        Hometeam         Guest           Result     Value  
LA Lakers       NY Knicks          H             1
Chicago Bulls   LA Lakers          G             1
LA Lakers      Houston Rockets     D           0 ```      Now how can I calculate the frequencies of LA LAkers won/lost previous game and won /lost current game. It should count all the possible four ordered pairs

Comment: @t.wangd It is difficult to understand through comments. I would suggest you to include sufficient number of rows in the example (let's say 20) do `dput(head(df, 20))`, where `df` is your dataframe and include it into your post by editing it. Calculate your expected output by hand and include that as well. It is easier to help if we can cross check our answers like that.

Comment: Hi @RonakShah, I've edited my question. Please have a look.

Comment: I don't understand what output do you expect from the code. Do you want text as `(won P, won C),(won P, Lost C),(Lost P, Won C), (Lost P, Lost C)` ?

Comment: No, I want the count of matches LA lakers lost after they won their previous match. If one row had the column value 1 then the next should be 0 and the result should be either H or G not D i.e it should not consider the rows containing D

Comment: and how many are they in the given example? Please update your post with exact output that you expect for the given example.

Comment: Similarly count of winning a match after winning previous match. There are 2 in the given example

Comment: @t.wangd Count of winning matches after winning the previous match can be found by `df %>%  summarise(total = sum(Value == 1 & lag(Value, default = 0) == 1))`

Comment: Is this for win and win? If yes, how to change for win and lose

Comment: Updated the answer. Can you check.

Comment: Thanks a lot . I really mean it. @RonakShah

Comment: sorry to ask again. what changes should I do if I have to check the previous two matches

Comment: you can use `lag` with `n = 2` like `lag(Value, 2)`. If you have a specific question you can ask as a new question so that it is better answered there instead of comments.

Answer (score 1):

```
df <- read_table("Hometeam         Guest           Result
LA Lakers       NY Knicks          H
Chicago Bulls   LA Lakers          G
LA Lakers      Houston Rockets     D
LA Lakers      Walsh HS            H
LA Lakers      Ga Tech             H
Akron Beacon    LA Lakers          G
New Orleans     LA Lakers          H")

ScoreCard <- df %>% 
  mutate(LAKERS.WON = case_when(
    Hometeam == "LA Lakers" & Result == "H" ~ TRUE,
    Guest == "LA Lakers" & Result == "G" ~ TRUE,
    TRUE ~ FALSE),
    LAK.WIN.NEXT = lead(LAKERS.WON),
    LAK.WIN.SUCCESIVE = LAKERS.WON & LAK.WIN.NEXT)

 Hometeam      Guest           Result LAKERS.WON LAK.WIN.NEXT LAK.WIN.SUCCESIVE
  <chr>         <chr>           <chr>  <lgl>      <lgl>        <lgl>            
1 LA Lakers     NY Knicks       H      TRUE       TRUE         TRUE             
2 Chicago Bulls LA Lakers       G      TRUE       FALSE        FALSE            
3 LA Lakers     Houston Rockets D      FALSE      TRUE         FALSE            
4 LA Lakers     Walsh HS        H      TRUE       TRUE         TRUE             
5 LA Lakers     Ga Tech         H      TRUE       TRUE         TRUE             
6 Akron Beacon  LA Lakers       G      TRUE       FALSE        FALSE            
7 New Orleans   LA Lakers       H      FALSE      NA           FALSE        


Win1 <- ScoreCard %>% 
  filter(LAKERS.WON)

with(Win1, sum(LAK.WIN.SUCCESIVE) / sum(LAKERS.WON))  
[1] 0.6
```

Comment: Hi @DavidT my question demands of creating a new column where I assign values of 1 for win , 0 for lost or draw. But from there I'm unable to figure out from there how to find the frequency....

Comment: I added more games to make the logic clearer.  The final `with` gives you your frequency.